# Webpack dynamic import with variable + externals config not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to use a dynamic import that uses a variable, and at the same time leave all these modules as external libraries, so I'm doing this:

`` import(`library/${module}.js`); ``

And my Webpack externals config is:

```
externals : /library\/.*\.js/
```

But this is not working.

If I do `` import(`library/specificModule.js`); `` it works.

Looks like the externals config doesn't apply for the import() with variables, because I also tried using a function as the externals config and setting up a brakpoint inside it, and it doesn't hit for those files.

Comment: `import()` with a variables does not work, unless it is inside a function that recieves that variable.

Comment: Im not showing all the code, but that import has the `module` variable on scope.